# Connect a string and a double in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to connect a `string` and a `double` in a `ArrayList` ?

It should look this way:

`[itemA 1, itemB 10, itemC 5, ...]`

I tried it with write the `double` also as `String` in the `ArrayList`, but then
 `Collections.sort(list)` won't sort the doubles correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's when you make a class.

```
class MyObject {
 private String someString;
 private double someDouble;
 // Getters & setters
}

List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can just keep a list of this custom object.

If you want to be able to sort your list on the `double` value, simply construct your class to implement the `Comparable` interface.

```
class MyObject : Comparable<MyObject>{
 private String someString;
 private double someDouble;

 @override
 public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
     return this.someDouble.compareTo(o.getSomeDouble());
 }
}
```

Comment: you should add an explanation on the sort process.

Comment: Yup, but it needs to be Comparable / have Comparator

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that this is a much better solution, but our professor wants us to save these items in a list, not in a class.

Comment: @rei0d: I don't believe that's what he means. You're still going to have a list with objects, only now you store the `String` and `double` together in one object. Did he explicitly tell you not to create a custom class?

Comment: No, we are allowed to create a class, but we have to put the items in a list. I think it is ok to have a list of objects. How can I add new items to this list now? I have sth like: static ArrayList<MyClass> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

Comment: Then this is the solution you're looking for :) `myArrayList.Add(new MyObject(somedouble, someString)`. Just create the appropriate constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html) from apache commons:

```
List<Pair<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new ImmutablePair<>("STRING", 2.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like, MyClass and create a String variable and double value.

Like,

```
class MyClass
{
   private String strVlaue;

   private String doubleValue;

   //Constructor using fields, and getter/setter method
}
```

Since you want to make it in order by double Value.

You can either make MyClass implement Comparable and implement custom order in compareTo method OR create a comparator for MyClass

**1 Implements Comparable**

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable {

private String strVlaue;

private double doubleValue;

public MyClass(String strVlaue, double doubleValue) {
    this.strVlaue = strVlaue;
    this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {

    MyClass mc = (MyClass) o;

    return Double.compare(this.doubleValue, mc.getDoubleValue());
}

public String getStrVlaue() {
    return strVlaue;
}

public void setStrVlaue(String strVlaue) {
    this.strVlaue = strVlaue;
}

public double getDoubleValue() {
    return doubleValue;
}

public void setDoubleValue(double doubleValue) {
    this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
}
}
```

Use **`Collections.sort(List<MyClass>)`** to sort.

**2 Keep MyClass not implement Comparable, create a comparator.**

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{

@Override
public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {

    return Double.compare(o1.getDoubleValue(), o2.getDoubleValue());
}

}
```

Use **`Collections.sort(List<MyClass>, new MyComparator())`** to sort.